# What is $1000 \choose 326$ $\mod{13}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

$1000=5(13^2)+11(13)+12$

$326=1(13^2)+12(13)+1$

Now, using Lucas theorem we have

$1000 \choose 326$$\equiv$$5 \choose 1$$11 \choose 12$$12 \choose 1$ $\pmod{13}$

Here, we got into the trouble since $11 \choose 12$ is not defined.

So, how do we compute this?

Comment: $\binom{m}{n}$ is assumed to be $0$ if $m<n$, so the result is zero.

Comment: @rogerl are you sure about this? Would you kindly give a reference?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

The exponent of 13 on the factorisation of $1000!$ is $\lfloor\frac{1000}{13}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{1000}{13^2}\rfloor$ do the same for $326!$ and $674!$ and you'll find that after dividing the exponent on 13 will be greater than one, so the residue modulo 13 is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can fast find n and k in t! = p^n * (p*m + k)  using recurrent 
t! = p^(t div p)  * ((t mod p)!  mod p ) * (-1)^(t div p)* (t div p)!
( (p-1)! mod p  = -1)

if n(1000, 13) > n(326, 13) + n(674, 13) - answer is 0, else answer is k(1000, 13)/(k(326, 13)*k(674, 13))

[simple codepad listing](http://codepad.org/25TiqpHr)
in your case answer is 0